# MVC- when are controllers needed?

Tags: magento, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am learning Magento and the MVC pattern and am struggling to grasp the concepts.

I'm trying to understand Controllers and when they are used.

Say, for example, I am building an interface that purely exports data in the background when an event is dispatched. If their is no views in use, then is it true to say that a Controller will not be needed?

When are controllers needed in an MVC application?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are the part of MVC that handles the user input. It takes data from the incoming request and distributes it to model layer structure (preferably - services).

Controllers have **nothing** to do with rendering of output. The closes it should come the influencing the response should be minor alteration of state for the view instance (for example, indicating to view to change output from HTML to JSON). Neither is controller responsible for trafficking data between model layer and views.

Comment: Yes, the rendering is the job of the view. But if there is no view, then is it fair to say that no controllers are necessary?

Comment: If no user action is anticipated no controller is needed

Comment: Reload of a page is "an action". In context of web, the "user" for MVC is you browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MVC concept in general, but Magento is pretty simple about controllers. Usually it all comes down to one question - **do you need a separate page to send HTTP queries (GET, POST, etc.) to?** If the answer is Yes - you need a controller, if No - you don't need a controller. I haven't seen any other usage of controllers in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function in a Controller which doesn't returns anything (void).

Comment: ... controllers should never return anything to begin with